# python built in reducebykey

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a built-in reducebykey functionality in python? If not, how can I imitate this functionality?

For example, if I'm doing a simple word count:

```
>>> x=[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)] 
>>> reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, x)
('a', 1, 'a', 1, 'b', 1, 'c', 1)
```

What I wanted is to have it return [('a',2), ('b',1), ('c',1)]. But the reduce() function just ended up iterating through all the tuples together, and didn't actually combine the keys. Any way around this?

Comment: What you are doing is *grouping*, not reducing. I don't think you fully understand what `reduce()` does.

Comment: Write a function that does what you want.  ```collections.defaultdict(int)``` should facilitate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **OrderedDict**. It will preserve the order also.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

result = OrderedDict()

for item in x:
    result[item[0]] = result.get(item[0], 0) + item[1]

result
[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```

Here, we are iterating over the dictionary. We look for the key `item[0]` in `result` ordereddict. If it is found, then we add `item[1]` which is 1 in  our case to the value already present there. Else, we take the default value as 0 and then add `item[1]`(this will happen when a element is encountered for the first time).

Comment: You should use `result[item[0]] += result.get(item[0], 0)` - otherwise you'll end up with wrong results if a) numbers other than `1` are present in the list or b) there are more than two items with the same key.

Comment: In the first iteration, it will lead to `keyerror  'a'` as key 'a' will not be present initially.

Comment: Ah, right, but then you at least need to use `item[1]` instead of `1`.

Comment: I had used 1 because word count was needed. If we need to add the values  for common keys, then we can use item[1]. Also, i had used `+=` approach as you suggested initially and arrived at this answer. ;)

Comment: My assumption was that 1 would be there always as the 2nd element of the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

As a more efficient way you can use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
>>> x=[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)] 
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d=defaultdict(int)
>>> for i,j in x:
...   d[i]+=j
... 
>>> d.items()
[('a', 2), ('c', 1), ('b', 1)]
```

Note that this doesn't preserve the order and if you care abut that you can use `collections.OrderedDict` intead of `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
d = defaultdict(int)
for a,b in x:
    d[a]  += b

print(d.items())
```

Or to guarantee you keep the order use an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
x = [('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
d = OrderedDict()
for a,b in x:
    d.setdefault(a,0)
    d[a] += b

print(list(d.items()))
[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: No, this is not what they are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to count same keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
x=[('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)] 
result = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for k, v in x:
    result[k] += v
```

Comment: I would have suggested the same thing, however you should be aware that this destroys any order the original sequence might have had.

Comment: Why the unnecessary `lambda`? `defaultdict(int)` is the canonical way to build a `defaultdict` that starts counting from `0`.